# NSToolbar - when can we access a ToolBarItem?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

NSToolbar `items` property is still empty on `windowDidLoad`

```
//WindowController

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad();

    print(window!.toolbar!.items);//print []
}
```

I am looking for a function called when all toolbar items are loaded.
Something like `ToolbarDidLoad`, or `ItemsDidLoad`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like awakeFromNib was the solution !

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib();

    print(window!.toolbar!.items);//print [<NSToolbarItem: 0x600000120c80>, <NSToolbarItem: 0x600000120d20>]
}
```